# New lithium ion battery cells stored in small cardboard boxes, potential fire risks?

Tags: lithium-ion, safety

I have some new lithium ion battery cells stored in individual small cardboard boxes at room temperature with low humidity.
Are there possible fire risks storing the battery cells like this?

I'm assuming that the biggest risk is puncture or impact damage during shipping (given lithium is [highly flammable](https://firefighterinsider.com/lithium-flammable/)).
But these battery cells pass the [UL-1642 certification](https://www.lipolbattery.com/UL1642_Certification_of_Lithium-ion_Battery.html), which states that under impact and crush testing,

> "The samples lithium-ion cells & lithium-ion batteries shall not
> explode or catch fire."

Comment: Not going to answer as I don't have industrial knowledge here, but cardboard has a higher autoignition temperature than most plastics (800 F vs 791 for pvc). Most plastics start melting at 400 F. Lithium batteries explode closer to 1000 F. Cardboard has much less sharp shrapnel. So theoretically cardboard is somewhat safer than your average pvc case.

Comment: And lithium cells are routinely stored, shipped, and retail sold in cardboard cases or plastic + cardstock blister packs. Even known bad ones! There are some different rules if you are shipping large amounts in a single box, but at any point you should be looking at the rules of your shipping carrier for lithium cells.

Comment: Actual cells and a web link a VERY good idea. Answer you have seems as good as any without more info. LiIon is generally safe enough if not provoked. SOME cells have failed under mechanical ical shock due to bad design or manufacture. Odds are yours wont but ... . I would never personally trust the safety if LiIon cells, while also still expecting them to be safe. Storage in a location where a worst case fire has least possible bad outcomes is wise.

Comment: Close queue cleared. The question is clear enough to be helpful to others.  More detail has been requested from OP. If provided it will be useful, but as is the question is useful.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, does it mean this question is no longer closed? There are some details I'd prefer to keep confidential and so would not be willing to provide more info. As-is, I am satisfied by the responses to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s normal practice for storage of this type of cell.  Unless they are involved in a fire that starts elsewhere the only significant risk is from short circuit.  Lithium cells have low self-discharge characteristics and so can be stored without maintenance provided they aren’t deeply discharged.  UL-1642 stipulates that the cells don’t ignite under certain test conditions, but that doesn’t mean they won’t go up in flames under *any* conditions.

Comment: BTW lithium cells don’t contain metallic lithium, however the liquid electrolyte does burn spectacularly

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the actual cells and a web link would be a VERY good idea.

The answer you have seems as good as any without more information.

LiIon is generally 'safe enough' if not provoked.
While eg new and properly stored NiCd, NiMh, Lead acid, ... cells are essentially certain to never catch fire, some LiIon have done so.

SOME cells have failed under mechanical shock due to bad design or manufacture. Percentage wise the numbers are extremely small, but some results have been spectacular. Both Apple and Samsung had major recalls due to faulty manufacture.

Odds are that yours won't but ... .    I would never personally trust the safety of LiIon cells, while also still expecting them to be safe. Storage in a location where a worst case fire has least possible bad outcomes is wise. Precautions are not hard to take and not overly costly.